# How to implement reference counting for library class whose implementation cant be changed?

Tags: c++

I come to know that when many objects shares same data and creation and desturction of objects are expensive then one can go for reference counting .

Can anybody give input about how to achieve it for the library class which cant be changed ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a referenced-counted pointer like `boost::shared_ptr`. No changes to the class pointed to are necessary, but you will be limited to creating class instances dynamically.

Comment: You can't use C++ effectively without using libraries. But you can simply copy the Boost source into your project.

Comment: If you are reference counting you always will create the object using new

Comment: @Deus By no means. Reference counted strings (as an example) do not have to be created using 'new'.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia article on referencing counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) states it better than I could:

> The main advantage of reference counting over tracing garbage collection is that objects are reclaimed as soon as they can no longer be referenced, and in an incremental fashion, without long pauses for collection cycles and with clearly defined lifetime of every object. In real-time applications or systems with limited memory, this is important to maintain responsiveness. Reference counting is also among the simplest forms of garbage collection to implement. It also allows for effective management of non-memory resources such as operating system objects, which are often much scarcer than memory (tracing GC systems use finalizers for this, but the delayed reclamation may cause problems). Weighted reference counts are a good solution for garbage collecting a distributed system.
>
> Tracing garbage collection cycles are triggered too often if the set of live objects fills most of the available memory; it requires extra space to be efficient. Reference counting performance does not deteriorate as the total amount of free space decreases.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)
>
> Reference counts are also useful information to use as input to other runtime optimizations. For example, systems that depend heavily on immutable objects such as many functional programming languages can suffer an efficiency penalty due to frequent copies. However, if we know an object has only one reference (as most do in many systems), and that reference is lost at the same time that a similar new object is created (as in the string append statement str ← str + "a"), we can replace the operation with a mutation on the original object.
>
> Reference counting in naive form has two main disadvantages over the tracing garbage collection, both of which require additional mechanisms to ameliorate:
>
> - The frequent updates it involves are a source of inefficiency. While tracing garbage collectors can impact efficiency severely via context switching and cache line faults, they collect relatively infrequently, while accessing objects is done continually. Also, less importantly, reference counting requires every memory-managed object to reserve space for a reference count. In tracing garbage collectors, this information is stored implicitly in the references that refer to that object, saving space, although tracing garbage collectors, particularly incremental ones, can require additional space for other purposes.
> - The naive algorithm described above can't handle reference cycles, an object which refers directly or indirectly to itself. A mechanism relying purely on reference counts will never consider cyclic chains of objects for deletion, since their reference count is guaranteed to stay nonzero. Methods for dealing with this issue exist but can also increase the overhead and complexity of reference counting — on the other hand, these methods need only be applied to data that might form cycles, often a small subset of all data. One such method is the use of weak references.

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass that inherits from the library's class, and implement reference-counting in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim Bruck mentioned, extension is one mechanism.  If extension is not possible, then you can use a delegating wrapper approach.